# Reusing the connection to the database

Tags: java, database, jdbc, database-connection

Until now, whenever I query the database I open a fresh connection to the database. How do I implement the property that once I open the connection I can reuse that?

With this done, please tell me if I could leak the resources.

Comment: @Preet Sangha i didn't understand you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically you need JDBC connection pool, typically implementing [`DataSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) interface. Have a look at [dbcp](/questions/tagged/dbcp) and [c3p0](/questions/tagged/c3p0). Chances are you container/server already provides an implementation of connection pooling.

When you use a connection pool every time you *open* a connection you are actually taking one from the pool (or opening if pool is empty). When *closing* the connection, it is actually returned to the pool. The leak can only occur if you forget the latter. <del>(or forget closing `ResultSet`, `Statement`...)</del>

Comment: i want to use it from different servlets

Comment: Why would there be a leak if a statement or resultset is not closed? Closing a connection closes them automatically, even if it's a pooled connection (or the contract of the close() method is broken)

Comment: @JBNizet: I am sure you are right, but can you post some reference? [`close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close()) is not mentioning about this.

Comment: For example, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html#pooled_connection says that using a pooled connection is transparent, and shows code that doesn't close the statement in a finally block. The javadoc you linked to says that database and JDBC resources associated with the connection are closed when the Connection.close() method is called. Whether the connection is physically closed or just released to the pool doesn't matter. It's the pool's responsibility to respect this contract.

Comment: Also look at close() and passivate() in http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/dbcp/trunk/src/java/org/apache/commons/dbcp2/DelegatingConnection.java?view=markup

Answer (score 1):

You can (and should) reuse db connections. Connection pooling is one of the techniques for this. A thorough tutorial on connection pooling can be read here : http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/conpool.html