# Is there a way to reuse database connections on my application?

Tags: java, mysql, database, connection

I have an application in Java, but I have a problem, when I do some operations\actions such as getting info from database or Insertion etc. the app create new connection. is it possible to let know for all process that connect already done. (something like static connection)...
I'm not good in programming, sorry in advance if question a bit stupid.

```
package dreamproject;

   import java.awt.Component;
   import javax.swing.JLabel;
   import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
   import java.awt.Component;

public class DiaryNotes {
DBConnect connect = new DBConnect();
private Component frame;

public void NoteCreation(int authorzedUserId,String title,String text,String date)
{
    try
    {

    String queryInsertNote = "INSERT INTO notes (authorzedUserId,title,text,date) VALUES ('"+ authorzedUserId +"','"+ title +"','"+ text +"','"+ date +"')";
    connect.statement.executeUpdate(queryInsertNote);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"The note has been created");

    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
    System.out.println("Error " + ex);
    }

}
```

}

AND IN ANOThER CLASS I CREATE OBJECT

```
    registr.registr(textRecord.getText(),title.getText(),confirmPasswordField.getText());
```

Comment: It's not a stupid question. You're looking for a database connection pool.

Comment: You must search about desing patterns

Comment: Can you post the code how you create your connection object? Others will be able to comment/suggest other/alternative approaches.

Comment: @AfsunKhammadli this is not related to design patterns.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773901/reusing-the-connection-to-the-database